# Unable to login with the Tenant user in wso2 server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Created user under tenant. I can even see my user in ldap.
But login fails when I am trying to login via IS management console.
The error shown after enabling user logs are :

```
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-04-30 06:51:49,527] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Authenticating with uid=due@due.com,ou=wso2,ou=system {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-04-30 06:51:49,538] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Authentication failed javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - INVALID_CREDENTIALS: Bind failed: Attempt to lookup non-existant entry: uid=due@due.com,ou=wso2,ou=system:
org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapNoSuchObjectException: Attempt to lookup non-existant entry: uid=due@due.com,ou=wso2,ou=system
        at org.apache.directory.server.core.shared.partition.DefaultPartitionNexus.lookup(DefaultPartitionNexus.java:459)
        at org.apache.directory.server.core.authn.AuthenticationInterceptor.bind(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:516)
        at org.apache.directory.server.core.DefaultOperationManager.bind(DefaultOperationManager.java:439)
        at org.apache.directory.server.ldap.handlers.request.BindRequestHandler.handleSimpleAuth(BindRequestHandler.java:178)
        at org.apache.directory.server.ldap.handlers.request.BindRequestHandler.handle(BindRequestHandler.java:625)
        at org.apache.directory.server.ldap.handlers.request.BindRequestHandler.handle(BindRequestHandler.java:66)
        at org.apache.directory.server.ldap.handlers.LdapRequestHandler.handleMessage(LdapRequestHandler.java:193)
        at org.apache.directory.server.ldap.handlers.LdapRequestHandler.handleMessage(LdapRequestHandler.java:56)
        at org.apache.mina.handler.demux.DemuxingIoHandler.messageReceived(DemuxingIoHandler.java:221)
        at org.apache.directory.server.ldap.LdapProtocolHandler.messageReceived(LdapProtocolHandler.java:217)
        at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:690)
        at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:417)
        at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:47)
        at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:765)
        at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterEvent.fire(IoFilterEvent.java:74)
        at org.apache.mina.core.session.IoEvent.run(IoEvent.java:63)
        at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.UnorderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(UnorderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:474)
        at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.UnorderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(UnorderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:428)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


BindRequest =
MessageType : BIND_REQUEST
Message ID : 1
    BindRequest
        Version : '3'
        Name : 'uid=due@due.com,ou=wso2,ou=system'
        Simple authentication : 'Due@123/0x44 0x75 0x65 0x40 0x31 0x32 0x33 '
] {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the logs.. It says `uid=due@due.com,ou=wso2,ou=system`.   Normally when you create a tenant, separate OU is created in the LDAP. Inside this OU,  there must be the user. It seems to be that WSO2IS tries to authenticate the user with invalid OU. Please verify your how you create the tenant and user..  This must be something specific to your environment.  If you take a fresh WSO2IS,  this would work properly. You can do some debug by enabling user.core debug logs. Then you can get more idea and find out which can be the root cause for issue.

> log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.user.core=DEBUG

You can add above in to `log4j.properties` file and restart the server and see.

Comment: Thanks. . Yes I see my tenant user  under different OU in ldap.  The logs I pasted here are the ones that I got after enabling user.core debug logs . Can you tellme what next I have to do in order to point to valid OU in ldap. Do I have to do changes in primary user store ?